# Where/how do I store configuration files in Unity development?

Tags: unity

I am transitioning from working with cocos2d-iphone to Unity.

One particular thing I loved were the `.plist` files: you could easily put any sort of configuration data you wanted: for game levels, stats, etc.

Now, with Unity, I am not entirely sure if I am supposed to be using such files. I suppose I can, but I'd rather adapt myself to whatever Unity developers use. What is the equivalent to property-list files in Unity development? Plain text files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For data that is created at design time you can use the [TextAsset](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextAsset.html) resource type. Note that despite its name it can be used for arbitrary binary data if preferred.

To persist data that is created at run time [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) provides a key-value store.  This will be implemented in a platform appropriate manner and performance may vary. If storing a large number of items at once is causing delays it may be improved by consolidating the data into a single sting.

To simplify parsing of this data many people use [SimpleJSON](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON).

Comment: Something to note: on Windows systems, PlayerPrefs writes to the Registry.

Answer (score 1):

[**Prefabs**](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Prefabs.html) : It is convenient to build a GameObject in the scene by adding components and setting their properties to the appropriate values.
Or you could write your own similar system. Check this [tutorial](http://www.lynda.com/Unity-3D-tutorials/Advanced-Unity-3D-Game-Programming/160270-2.html) written by @Byte56.

Comment: I'm not sure if Prefabs are meant to be used for this sort of data storage. One usage example could be a history of purchases, with transaction details for each entry - a .plist file would be pretty nice in this scenario. I was imagining that there was a file format similar to this within Unity development - or perhaps I should go for a generic XML parser.

Comment: You are right a generic XML parser would be the way to go. However, I noticed that someone has written plist parser. Try it out : http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=PropertyListSerializer. You could also achieve the same using sqlite database : http://wgcreativesolutions.wordpress.com/2014/01/23/using-sqlite-database-in-unity3d-4-3-3f/.

Comment: I think [this is a more direct link to the tutorial](http://www.lynda.com/Unity-3D-tutorials/Creating-your-own-prefab-system/160270/177256-4.html) you're talking about. And while it is possible to write those custom prefabs on the fly in game, to save settings, it's not the simplest solution to the problem. Some sort of simple text file is probably best. Thanks for the support though :)

Comment: Thanks @Byte56 but as op mentioned he wanted to "One usage example could be a history of purchases, with transaction details for each entry" don't you think that saving this data as plain text would make the game vulnerable to hacks?

Comment: It would be vulnerable to hacking, but op didn't mention security as a concern. Further, just because it's in a text file doesn't mean it can't be obfuscated or encrypted. My point was more along the lines of, just write a file, don't get to complicated to start with. On the other hand, I voted for your answer because a few of the examples in the original post would be well suited for prefabs.